# Minimizing distance from origin on a curve.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Ahoy!

I've recently encountered a problem that is intended to be solved using Lagrange multipliers, but I'm trying to solve it without using them.

Problem:

**Which points on the curve $$5x^2+4xy+2y^2=6$$
are closest to the origin?**

My initial idea was that there will be a set of points with tangent vectors orthogonal to the position vectors at the given point, satisfying $$<f(x,y),\nabla f(x,y)>=0,$$ and I'd only have to calculate the norms of the vectors in this set and find the minimum, or if the curve is parametrized $$(x-\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)+(y-\psi(t))\psi'(t)=0.$$

I'm having trouble parameterizing the curve though, as I can't separate out the mixed term $4xy$.

As this curve is, at least at first glance, an ellipse, so my other idea was to find a linear transformation that would rotate this ellipse such that it's semiaxes lie along the coordinate axes, in which case I could find the points at which it intersects the coordinate axes and feed those position vectors into the inverse matrix of my linear transformation to get the original position vectors with minimal distance to the origin before the transformation.

I don't know enough linear algebra to do this, and it seems to me that in order to find the appropriate angle to rotate this curve by I would need to know the angle which the position vector of the closest point to the origin closes with the x-axis to begin with, which would solve my problem without need for the rotation...

Please give me some pointers on how to solve this task without use of Lagrange multipliers!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are $\gamma$ and $\psi$  here?

Comment: @AspiringMathematician
$\gamma(t)$ and $\psi(t)$ would be two functions parameterizing the initial function.

For example, in the case of the unit circle we observe that
$$x^2+y^2=1 \rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt{1-y^2}.$$

Hence, the top half of the unit circle can be parameterized by the positive branch of the equation as
$$\gamma(t)=\sqrt{1-t^2}\\ \psi(t)=t,\\ \textrm{where } t\in[-1,1]$$

The specific problem with this function is that there is a mixed term, $4xy$, which makes this kind of parameterization difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your method,  but another way is to look at it as minimizing $x^2+y^2$  (Technically the square root of that,  but distance is minimized when distance squared is minimized and it's easier to work with the latter) for points on your curve.

Now, you can view the curve as a quadratic equation in y:

$$2y^2+(4x)y+(5x^2-6)=0$$
and use either completing the square or the equivalent quadratic formula with $a=2,  b=4x,  c=5x^2-6$ to find the solutions for $y$ in terms of x.  Note there will be two of them as the graph is not a function.

Then you can just plug those values of $y$ into $x^2+y^2$ and you are reduced to a function in a single variable $x$ which you can minimize by 1 variable means,  taking derivative,  finding critical points, etc.

I'm not sure how feasible/calculable that route is,  but it's the other main way you can do problems of "Optimize a function subject to a constraint":  Solve the constraint for one variable and plug into function to reduce it to a lower variable function